# "scrambled for a hold" vs "scrabbled for a hold"

Tags: word-choice

While throwing together some prompts for a [writing challenge on Writing.CD](https://writing.codidact.com/questions/74854) last night, I wrote this line:

> [My] hands scrambled for a hold on the rough rock.

This morning, while looking back at it, I thought "Huh. Is it actually "*scrambled*", or should that be "*scrabbled*"? I seem to recall seeing "*scrabbled*"."

So, [turning to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scrabbled+for+a+hold%22&oq=%22scrabb&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57.1756j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), I did a quick search for the line "scrabbled for a hold".

[image: Search results for "scrabbled for a hold": About 7,440 results]

And then, to compare, a [search for "scrambled for a hold"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03lltqI8Z5nujTydk-wpNPd4mkhmA%3A1588843148566&ei=jNKzXqidIqaHjLsPssKWSA&q=%22scrambled+for+a+hold%22&oq=%22scrambled+for+a+hold%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCCMQrgIQJ1DLOlj7PGCmQGgAcAB4AIABrAGIAZoEkgEDMC40mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiok-X7taHpAhWmA2MBHTKhBQkQ4dUDCAw&uact=5).

[image: Search results for "scrambled for a hold": About 13,600 results]

...so it looks like both are in use, but "scrambled" is slightly more popular?

Except that Google Ngrams shows a different story.

[image: graph showing "scrambled for a hold" vs "scrabbled" for a hold over time. "scrambled" makes an appearance in about 1907, while "scrabbled" waits until the late 1930s. However, "scrabbled" is much more popular now]

The graph shows that even though "scrambled for a hold" makes an appearance nearly thirty years before "scrabbled for a hold" shows up, by the 1950s "scrabbled" has outstripped "scrambled" and is more in-use.

But... which one is actually *correct*? Does it matter which one popped up first, or that the other one became more popular? Which one is actually more accurate?

Comment: Definitely not *scrambled*. *Scrabbled* refers to a digging or clawing action. Both scrambled and scrabbled are usually  applied to a whole person, not just the hands. They imply an action driven by a state of mind and don't seem to be idiomatic when disembodied as in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and are synonyms in the usage here  considered. Both are traced back to a much more ancient period than that shown by the ngrams, since "scrabble" was acknowledged in the mid 17th century and "scramble" in the late 16th.

> (SOED) **scrabble** [MDu *schrabbelen* …] **3** *v.i.* Scramble on hands and feet; stumble or struggle along;
>    Freq. foll. by *up*. M17.
>
> (SOED) **scramble** [ imitation: cf. CRAMBLE, SCAMBLE] **1** *v.i.* Stand up, get into a specified place or position, by the struggling use of the hands and the feet; make one's way by clambering, crawling, etc. over steep or rough ground; move hastily or awkwardly into a specified place or position. L16.

Popularity is very relative criterion but there is a tendency driving people to opt for the popular; I wouldn't say that scramble is more accurate but that it appears to carry more connotations in the way of expressing the idea of a struggling with one's body.

Comment: I see "scrambled" as suggesting the hands - or people or whatever - fell over each other racing or otherwise competing for a hold.

I think "scrabbled" suggests the hands - or people or whatever - struggled for a hold.

Both imply struggle but - albeit tenuously and only when there's a choice, in scrambling the struggle is prolly against other competitors; in scrabbling, not necessarily against anything but the terrain.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin That seems  right; there is this [old definition](https://books.google.fr/books?id=k48NAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA674&dq=%22scrabble+to%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLg6uR6qLpAhVKyYUKHbw8ATkQ6AEIXTAF#v=onepage&q=%22scrabble%20to%22&f=false): "to claw or rake together". According to what I could find the idea in "scrabble" would essentially be that of a struggle against the terrain, I agree, but even in that limited domain "scrabble" is apparently not much used nowadays.

Comment: Really? I suggest "scrabble" is used nowadays. In many a field of fact or fiction where people compete, they often "scrabble" for advantage, for dominance, for power or anything remotely like those.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Strangely enough, a search on Google Books reveals that  no instance is found of the verb and that the literature is absolutely swamped by the noun, which is invariably the noun of the game.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=pXy6XurQCumq1fAPk72f6Aw&q=scrabble+as+a+verb&oq=scrabble+as+a+verb&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15399.18364.0.19210.18.16.0.2.2.0.117.1349.14j2.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.9.579...0.0.qL4Q3MWh2Nc

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I haven't examined this collection in depth and there are in it some rare occurrences such as 
"to manage to get on"  (Surrey Words, 1876), "men will do to shy away from or scrabble towards love, but he has never felt it course incontrovertibly though his body."(2014), and "it's a hard scrabble for the poor" (1891), but on the whole it contains a mass of dictionary references and even, again, a large number of references to the game.

Comment: You don't need the individual references Posting, do you?

I do understand that a bunch of cheats bought the dictionary in order to fill it with words normal readers or players could ever have met but even that hardly explains this nonsense.

You do recognise, don't you, that "scrabble" is still used as a verb, most often for advantage or dominance, for power or the like?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I think I can be sure that "scrabble" is used figuratively (along the line of the meaning you give:  struggling for advantage…power), as various definitions showing a similar figurative meaning can be found; they must necessarily reflect an established usage; however, the number of examples of it in the sources Google can access is far from impressive.

Comment: Great and where does "figuratively" come into this?

I'm glad I'm not responsible for your or Google's experience.

Did you not know about, for instance, The Dead Poets' Society?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "Figurative" should be taken as opposed to the primary (literal) meaning which involves the idea of using your hands; by the way here is OALD's definition: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/scrabble?q=scrabble. No, I didn't know about  Dead Poets society before you mentioned it and that should be a film, I believe. It rhymes strangely with this question there was yesterday on the ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/533924/349876

Comment: Great and I'm now doubly glad I'm not responsible for your or Google's experience. 

It's in no way necessary to have watched The Dead Poets' Society and this would be many times easier if you had. Could you?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin. Yes, I think both are acceptable, and while there is broadening the extent of which dictionaries only hint at, to me 'scrabble' _strongly suggests_ 'scrattin' about (in the loose/angular terrain)' whereas 'scramble' _strongly suggests_ more whole-body exertion, and _suggests_ a scrum.