# kindergarten “readiness,” to society’s detriment

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Children have become less emotionally expressive, less energetic, less talkative and verbally expressive, less humorous, less imaginative, less unconventional, less lively and passionate, less perceptive, less apt to connect seemingly irrelevant things, less synthesizing, and less likely to see things from a different angle.” Who or what could we blame except parents and an educational system that often squash original thinking and penalize students for using their imagination? **Our students get the message rather quickly from our obsession with kindergarten “readiness,” to society’s detriment.**
Permission to Feel by Marc Brackett

what does the bold part mean

Comment: Did you google for "kindergarten readiness"?

Comment: **Readiness** - the state of being prepared (by education and/or experience)  for the commencement [of something.]

Comment: [Children do not develop their full potential as parents and education system suck] "We focus too much on formal measurements. The kids see this. As a result the whole society suffers."

Answer (score -1):

"Kindergarten 'readiness'" has to be understood as in the following [paragraph](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QeGANNwablsC&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=with+kindergarten+%E2%80%9Creadiness,%E2%80%9D+to+society%E2%80%99s+detriment.&source=bl&ots=kYpRhTwytu&sig=ACfU3U3Qumv6ifq_TYOL_fIi8LfUuFIurQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjniqHroqzpAhUlAWMBHQmBD9sQ6AEwA3oECGIQAQ#v=onepage&q=with%20kindergarten%20%E2%80%9Creadiness%2C%E2%80%9D%20to%20society%E2%80%99s%20detriment.&f=false), where the use of "readiness" is not taken as interpretable.

[image]

In "readiness" must be read the idea of preparedness; "school readiness" is the ability acquired or not through formal training to face up to the challenge of being a student. The obsession with school readiness is a euphemism for the insistence from parents that their children should conform to certain necessary standards (early reading skills, etc.) while at the same time remaining impervious to all influence stimulating creativity and personal inspiration. It is this possibly too great involvment that they demand of the children that is the cause of the problem because it is attained at the detriment of their spiritual development. "The students get the message quickly" means that the students understand early what is expected of them and conform to a somewhat depersonalizing behaviour geared rather towards performance than self-expression. "To society's detriment" means that this loss in power of self-expression affects society adversely.

Comment: The first paragraph of this is not English. The last is unsourced.